# How to do long-running operations on a Java application server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns

[We are using JBoss 6, but I believe this question applies to any JaveEE application server]

We have an application server, which (among other things) is supposed to carry out some really long-running task (can take up to hours).

The task is triggered by calling some EJB function, but so far, the entire operation is running within this function call, and hence within the EJB transaction. Such transactions time-out rather quickly, and just extending the transaction timeout does not seem to be the correct solution.

The overall task could easily be split into load/work/store parts, so there doesn't seem to be a strict requirement to have a transaction for the entire time.

So the question is: What is the "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not completely sure that it was possible to see this from my question, but I found the answer I was looking for]

Some piece of work can be scheduled by a [WorkManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html).

See http://danielveselka.blogspot.de/2012/03/schedule-jobs-with-workmanager.html for some pointers to articles about it.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely request you to have a look at [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). This is amazing tool to schedule the task at specific interval. We used Quartz in one of our project and it was great. Our scenario was to take the input from used from from post in form of Excel files and then process those huge excels asynchronously which could take long time, what we did was take the input and schedule a job to run just after 1 sec. Spring also has support of job scheduling using quarts and Jboss comes pre-packaged with quarts.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to Quartz. Where can I find some more information about the architecture behind this? Especially, how does using Quartz jobs avoid the transaction problem?

Comment: You can go through tutorials available on Quarts site itself http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/ . For the transaction, What we did was just submit the task to Quartz and that will run the task in asynchronously so that we can send response back to user, and there onwards refresh the page periodically to check the updates. I believe in your case also you can something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The general correct way of doing this is putting these tasks as job and then processing them asynchronously. Spring has an inbuilt framework for this. But in general you can put the long task in queue , process it separately out side webapplication and then notify user via email, or provide user a link where they can check for status.